# General criteria to choose a domain extension

Tags: domain-extension

For a domain of a non-profit or non-governmental organization a `.org` extension is much better than say a `.com`, or the other way around for a private company. But I'd like to know if general and more or less "official" criteria exist about how to choose the domain extension based on the type of the website (for example, [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/) has `.net` but it's one of the very few, and most websites in that field are `.com`, what criteria might be behind the `.net` choice) and perhaps also based on possible law-related particularities of some extensions (the latter is less relevant).

I tried to search about this subject but the info I found are from quite obscure sources unknown to me, so I wanted to ask here.

Comment: Are there laws or regulations, of any kind, concerning top level domains? I don't think so. I'm pretty sure this will all be opinion.

Comment: @Rob Last time I registered a domain (in Italy) there were differences in what - or whether - official documents identifying the owner were required for different extensions, so I imagined that there might be other such differences. For example I'm not sure everybody can register a `.gov` domain. But I might be wrong, I'm very ignorant about this subject.

Comment: Please don't use "F.ex." for "for example". I had no clue what you meant by that. We aren't short of space here.

Comment: @Rob My apologies, I thought it was common. I edited my previous comment about that and thanks for doing the same in my question. By the way the legal aspect - or lack of it - is a minor one for my question; I am more interested in the criteria about the "meaning" of an extension, like my example about `.org` vs. `.com`.

Comment: Does link from [wikipedia about tld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) does not help you to understood about it?

Comment: @Goyllo It probably will, thanks. I had not found it. I did not even know that what I call extension is also called "top level domain".

Comment: Glad to hear that. [This information from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) might be also help you (Don't forgot to click on (More about domain determination) drop down container class).

Comment: @Goyllo Your two comments are a perfect fit for my question. If you put that into an answer I would mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net .org and .com are considered as top level domain(TLD) and are public TLD so anyone can register easily from any domain register company.

People sometimes use .net when .com are not available for registration. While people use .org when they provide some information or service for free.

Link from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) and [Google article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) might be helpful.